# SQL Server database backup file (.bak ) file gets corrupted

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I have been working on a SQL Server database designing since long now and I have observed that when a .bak file is mailed or kept and downloaded from ftp site, it gets corrupted.

When I try to restore, it gives me 3013 error code with messsage:

> "Backup or restore operation terminating abnormally.

I tried `RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM DISK='C:\abc.bak'` as well but it says

> VERIFY DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Any idea why this is happening and also, is there a better way to move the database file from one server to another (I do not have the access to source server)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Long as you do a binary download in FTP the file should not be corrupt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For FTP make sure that you use binary mode.
Did you try to send plain attachment to yourself and compare the results with the files from sent and received email?

Comment: Yes I tried downloading the sent file as well and received file as well. but they both are corrupted. Any idea why?

Comment: If the sent version does not work check that the version that you were trying to attach works. If that does work, check how you attach the file - any weird connection issues, try using webmail and email client to send an email and compare the results. I am startign to suspect that your bak file gets corrupted before it is attached or downloaded, make sure that you can restore new database from the backup immediately.

Comment: I did it and the attached version works fine. This are the steps I followed:

1) Backup a db and check if it can be restored: Yes 

2) Upload .bak file and save it in draft and check: Yes

3) Send a file to someone and check the sent file: No

4) Check the received file: No

Comment: OK, if your sent and received versions of the file do not work - which email client are you using? Did you try webmail?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61336304/2118383)

You may need to repair your mdf file first using some tools. There are lot of tool available in the market. There is tool called **Restore MS SQL Database** which is very useful to repair the mdf files.

The issue might me because of corrupted transaction logs, you may use tool [Restore MS SQL Database](https://www.stellarinfo.com/sql-database-toolkit.php) to repair your corrupted mdf file.